# Multichart(NVD3) x-axis labels not displaying

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Greeting,

I am new to NVD3 and I am struggling to have X-axis displayed (in my case different months) for **multiChart** graph.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx0jtco2/4/)  for the same.

**Observation :** If I have 2 y-axis("yAxis": 1 & "yAxis":2) in my data, the X axis appears, but my requirement is that I have only 1 yAxis.

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I just changed the order of the Dataset in my response, moved the line dataset first and it started working.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j44kumjc/2/)

Comment: Now the x-axis is not inline with the bar graph, could some1 help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with this nvd3 version for multiChart if you want to work with only 1 yAxis, try upgrading that to latest version.